# Jackson: Serialise Map<Object, Object>

Tags: jackson, jpa-2.0, jackson2

I have the following classes:

```
public class A {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String value;
}

public class B {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private Map<A, C> map;
}

public class C {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String object;
}
```

When I try to serialize class B, I get something like this:

```
{
   "id":52,
   "map":{
      "com.project.model.A@5abbb6ce":{
         "id":12,
         "object":"some string"
      },
      "com.project.model.A@1d1c0771":{
         "id":15,
         "object":"another string"
      }
   }
}
```

How can I make Jackson use the id of class C as a key, instead of the whole object?

E.g

```
{
   "id":52,
   "map":{
      "5":{
         "id":12,
         "object":"some string"
      },
      "7":{
         "id":15,
         "object":"another string"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hoped to find a simpler solution but ended up implementing a custom serializer.

```
public class B {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = CustomASerializer.class)
    private Map<A, C> map;
}



public class CustomASerializer extends JsonSerializer<A> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(A a, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(String.valueOf(a.getId()));
    }
}
```